# Efficient way of Comparing Counts of 3 different lists

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement

I have 3 list objects and I need them to all have the same count.. or all be empty (Count = 0).

If one or more lists has a larger/smaller count than the other list(s) then I need to catch that.

Is there a more efficient way of writing this then doing multiple if statements?

```
public static bool ThreeListComparison(List<string> lstOne,
    List<int> lstTwo, List<decimal> lstThree)
{
    var firstLstCount = lstOne.Count;
    var secondLstCount = lstTwo.Count;
    var thirdLstCount = lstThree.Count;

    if ((firstLstCount == 0 || secondLstCount == 0 || thirdLstCount == 0) && (firstLstCount != 0 || secondLstCount == 0) &&
        (firstLstCount == 0 || secondLstCount != 0)) return true;

    if (firstLstCount == 0 && secondLstCount != 0) return false;

    if (firstLstCount != 0 && secondLstCount == 0) return false;

    if (firstLstCount == 0 || secondLstCount == 0) return true;

    return firstLstCount == secondLstCount;
}
```

This is what I've started with two lists, but after writing it I am hoping for a better way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's really not clear why you don't simply[check if all lists have the same count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52225234/284240)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think I was too deep.. for some reason.. when comparing objects I immediately think `if` statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since zero is a perfectly valid integer number, comparing all three lists for zero count is redundant. You can rely on transitive property of equality to do the check with a simple `&&` statement:

```
return lstOne.Count == lstTwo.Count && lstTwo.Count == lstThree.Count;
```

Comment: Thank you for the simplicity

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = new[] { firstLstCount , secondLstCount , thirdLstCount};
```

To check if they are the same count

```
return arr.Distinct().Count() == 1
```

Comment: Well these lists will more than likely have values in them.. so how do I check for the same count (could be >= 0) for each list?

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple way to check an unlimited number of lists using LINQ?:

```
public static bool ListComparison(params List<string>[] lists)
{
    return lists.All(l => l.Count == lists[0].Count);
}
```

Comment: @Tim True, but all other answers have the same issue :) And `lists` is empty wouldn't pose a problem because it would never iterate.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq
```

Make an array of lists:

```
List<string>[] lists = new List<string>[] { firstLst, secondLst, thirdLst };
```

Then calculate the maximum array size:

```
int maxSize = lists.Max(list => list.Count);
```

And then respond if any of them is different size:

```
if(!lists.All(list => list.Count == maxSize))
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract `firstListCount` from `secondListCount` and `thirdListCount`. If all three are zero, then they all match. For example:

```
return new[] { 0, secondLstCount - firstLstCount, thirdLstCount - firstLstCount }.All(x => x == 0)
```

Comment: If they are all 5, then it will be { return new[] { 0, 0, 0 }.All(x => x == 0) }, which will return TRUE correctly